# Woocommce: Category Product Page with products grouped by a Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, hook-woocommerce

I need to show a Category Product Page (Woocommerce)and grouped them by a Custom Taxonomy which is created the Custom Post Type (CPT) plugin.

Here a capture to see what I mean: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1JDxGOO2CCq6aGSUwzows7wtAn9DmshCF7M8g-PdcdUc/edit?usp=sharing

Here the Custom Post Type (CPT) plugin: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Is there a way to do this? I think of a HOOK for the Category page where I can get the Custom Taxonomy value to group the product and finally print them out... not sure.

Should I start with this?

```
    /***********************************************************/
    /**********  CATEGORY GROUPED BY CPT TAXONOMY  ************/
    /***********************************************************/
    // define the woocommerce_shop_loop callback 
    function my_woocommerce_shop_loop( $array, $int ) { 
        Fetch products and Custom Taxonomies values to group them.    
    }; 

    // add the action 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'my_woocommerce_shop_loop', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: @disinfor I am afraid I don't know how to start with this.

Comment: @JPashs Is the category page dynamic or is it always static?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the exact solution to what you are asking but it's an alternate and it may help, so I'm posting it.

Either using a plugin or not, a way to loop through the `terms` of your `taxonomy` and display the items of each term, is the below code

```
  <?php
     $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_HERE',
    ]);
    foreach($terms as $term) {
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_HERE',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term->slug,

          )
        )
      );
      $the_new_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
      if ( $the_new_query->have_posts() ) : 
        echo '<h1>'.$term->name.'</h1>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_new_query->have_posts() ) : $the_new_query->the_post();
        '<li>'.the_title().'</li>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
      endif;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Not sure how to wrap your code inside my action function: `function my_woocommerce_shop_loop( $array, $int ) { `